# Display contents from custom post type in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using [Types](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/types) plugin for create a Wordpress Custom Post Type (CPT), now I need to display that content. I have created a page called: `category-legislaciones.php` where `legislaciones` is the category, from the CPT itself, created using Types plugin. This is the code I have on that page:

```
<?php
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'legislaciones', 'posts_per_page' => 15 );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
?>
<h1 class="post-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

<?php $options = get_option( 'responsive_theme_options' ); ?>
<?php if ( $options['breadcrumb'] == 0 ): ?>
    <?php echo responsive_breadcrumb_lists(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
    <div class="post-entry">
        <?php the_content( __( 'Read more &#8250;', 'responsive' ) ); ?>
        <?php wp_link_pages( array(
            'before' => '<div class="pagination">' . __( 'Pages:', 'responsive' ),
            'after'  => '</div>'
        )); ?>
    </div>
    <?php if ( comments_open() ) : ?>
        <div class="post-data">
            <?php the_tags( __( 'Tagged with:', 'responsive' ) . ' ', ', ', '<br />' ); ?>
                <?php the_category( __( 'Posted in %s', 'responsive' ) . ', ' ); ?>
        </div><!-- end of .post-data -->
    <?php endif; ?>

        <div class="post-edit"><?php edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'responsive' ) ); ?></div>
    </div><!-- end of #post-<?php the_ID(); ?> -->

    <?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>
        <?php if ( $wp_query->max_num_pages > 1 ) : ?>
            <?php if ( function_exists( 'wp_paginate' ) ) {
                wp_paginate();
            } ?>
        <?php endif; ?>

    <?php get_search_form(); ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

But nothing is display even if I have content assigned to that category, what I am doing wrong? What is the right way to display that contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are mixing 
Custom Post Type (post_type => 'post_type' => 'legislaciones') 
and Custom Taxonomy,

or do you really have both Custom Post Type and Custom Taxonomy with the same slug ?

If your legislaciones is a Custom Post Type, the proper name for your file would be archive-legislaciones.php and you don't need a specific query

If your legislaciones is a Custom Taxonomy, then here you are basically calling for the posts with post_type legislaciones and the Taxonomy legislaciones with a value which would be determined in the url

This is all detailed in the Codex, the page about [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy)

It does not belong to your question, but your code will repeat breadcrumb and comment form 15 times on the page, is this really what you want ?